# Button inside a listboxitem ignoring clicks when its parent listboxitem is selected

Tags: wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I have a listbox whose listboxitem contains, among other things, a button, as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="cDataTemplate" DataType="x:Type utils:cd">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource LIButton}" x:Name="CButton" 
                Command="{x:Static this:EditorCommands.RaiseCMenu}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}">
            <Image Name="Image" Source="icon_c.jpg" Width="33" Height="21"/>
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="ctxtCard">
                    <MenuItem Header="..." Command="{x:Static this:EditorCommands.abc}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="..." Command="{x:Static this:EditorCommands.def}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
        <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left">
...
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left">
...
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="cListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource cDataTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border
                         Name="Border"
...
                         Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter Name="Content" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0.55"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When the button in a listboxitem that is not selected is clicked, it fires its command, which raises the context menu in code-behind and selects the button's parent listboxitem.  (The whole point is to raise the context menu on left-click.)  But for the life of me, I can't get the button to fire the command when its parent listboxitem is already selected.  Oddly, if the button inside a selected listboxitem is right-clicked, it duly raises its context menu, so the button is receiving clicks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this happens when the selectionmode on a listbox is set to extended.  I'll update this question if I ever find a way around it.